# Associates the same model twice through different name

Tags: postgresql, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement a lost and found database.
I have two model, `User` and `Item`. A user can lost an an item and found an item. And a item can have a the user who found it and the user who lost it. I want to be able to reference the the same model through different name, e.g.

```
user.found_items, user.lost_items, item.founder, item.losser
```

right now I am able to do:

`user.founds`, `user.losts` and `user.items` will return the `items` from losts

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :founds
  has_many :items, through: :founds

  has_many :losts
  has_many :items, through: :losts
end

class Lost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

class Found < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :found
  has_one :user, through: :found

  has_one :lost
  has_one :user, through: :lost
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something pretty similar just rename them for clarity and add some methods for the functions you wanted.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :found_items
  has_many :items, through: :found_item

  has_many :lost_items
  has_many :items, through: :lost_item

  def items_found
    self.found_items.map {|i| i.item.name }
  end

  def items_lost
    self.lost_items.map {|i| i.item.name }
  end

end

class LostItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

class FoundItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :found_item
  has_one :user, through: :found_item

  has_one :lost_item
  has_one :user, through: :lost_item

  def finder
    self.found_item.user.name
  end

  def loser
    self.lost_item.user.name
  end
end
```